# How to detect which data are affecting the result of a feature with machine learning?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Firstly, I will illustrate the scenario that I have a dataset like;

ProductID, ProductType, MachineID, MachineModel, MachineSpeed, RejectDate, RejectVolume etc.

And I want to find which field(s) is the reason for the increase in my RejectVolume? Also, in the scenario, all products have a RejectVolume. I mean RejectVolume is nonzero and there are continuous but different values. Thanks to this, I can recognize the reason(s) and find the solution for reducing the value of RejectVolume.

Can you give me any ideas for creating the model?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at [Feature Selection methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection).

In this scenario you could start with [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) using [Lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) for feature selection. This is done by successively increasing the lasso regularization term, which will decrease the weight of unimportant features, leaving you with the features with the most impact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it but what is the next step for this problem. I mean, I have a new dataset with important features but which algorithms should I use for the training dataset and other processes?

Comment: @NevzatGünay, sorry I do not understand your question. Do you want to find important features or build a predictive model on your data? To build a model you have to try different ML algorithms. It is not possible to tell you which one to use without any knowledge about the data.

Comment: I mean that I want to find important features for the reason and I want to automate this. Also, when the machine produces the data, the model can predict the reason why the RejectVolume value is increasing.

Comment: @NevzatGünay it seems you have to elaborate a bit more what the problem is. For the Lasso approach: When you have the data you 1) want to build a linear regression model that has high predictive power meaning it can predict the RejectVolume quite accurately. 2) increase the lasso regularization term and monitor which features get canceled out. Where do you have problems step 1 or 2?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right that I want to find out the two steps. Now, I have just dataset and I have no idea how I can start to solve the problems.